# How to define an object in the ggplot?

Tags: r, object, ggplot2

I created and run the code few weeks before, and it works perfectly well for me. However, when I run the code yesterday, it showed me some error as below:

```
Error in filter(., type == "P.Probability") : object 'type' not found
In addition: Warning message:
In data.matrix(data) : NAs introduced by coercion
```

I tried to run the `dtf2_long`, knowing that `type` is the column name for 2nd column and is defined already in `dtf2_long`, so I'm not sure why R Studio unable to find `type`.

```
library(ggplot2)

Month <- c("Aug", "Sep", "Oct")
P.Probability <- c(0.5, 0.6, 0.6)
N.Probability <- 1-P.Probability

dtf2 <- data.frame(Month, N.Probability, P.Probability)

dtf2_long <- tidyr::gather(dtf2, type, Probability, -Month)

ggplot(dtf2_long, aes(x = Month, y = Probability, fill = type)) + 
  geom_bar(stat = "identity", position = position_fill(reverse = TRUE)) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept=0)+
  theme(axis.title.y=element_blank(),
        axis.title.x=element_blank(),
        plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0.5),
        plot.subtitle = element_text(hjust = 0.5))+
  theme(panel.background = element_blank(),
        axis.ticks.x = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.line.y = element_line(color="black", size = 0.5))+
  geom_text(data = dtf2_long %>% filter(type == "P.Probability"),
            aes(label = paste(Probability*100, "%"), vjust = ifelse(Probability >= 0, -0.5, 1.2)))+
  scale_y_continuous(labels=scales::percent)
```

Comment: It looks like you're calling `stats::filter`, make sure you call `dplyr::filter` instead. This is probably because you haven't called `library(dplyr)` in this session, while you did previously

Comment: Where should I add `dplyr::filter` into my code? I tried to run `library(dplyr)` already, but still the same error

Comment: The code seems to work on the data that you have provided.

Comment: Yes, I get the error you got, until I add `library(dplyr)` at the top and run again, then it's fine. Issue also resolved if I replace `filter(type ==...` with `dplyr::filter(type==...`

Comment: Ya, I manage to get the output already, thanks everyone for helping me! :)